# Телеграмм-бот, который напоминает тебе о распорядке

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Лазал по гуглу и так и не смог понять, а как же все-таки заставить бота в фоне делать какие-то дела и отправлять их мне, когда наступает час X. Есть разные предположения: cron, while + sleep. Но второй способ не совсем рабочий, а первый я пока не пробывал, но даже если так, в документации telebot того же не увидел как отправлять сообщения просто без обращения к боту.

В общем, помогите. Потратил вчера вечер, но так и не нашел решения, хотя знаю, что это возможно, так как есть куча ботов, которые постят что-то в чат без обращения к ним :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте доку больше.
Вот пример популярной библиотеки - https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

Ниже кусок простого кода, где text - текст вашего сообщения строкой, а chat_id - это ваш айдишник в телеге. Айдишник можно получить у этого бота `@getmyid_bot`. С токеном, думаю, все понятно и так.

```
tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
tb.send_message(chat_id, text)
```

Хотя бы одно сообщение своему боту отправьте, после чего он сможет вам писать.

Comment: Спасибо большое. До этого пытался делать тоже самое, игнорируя чат id. Теперь понял свою ошибку